# Doing a .contains() on HashTables of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, replace, hashtable

Say I have the following two structures:

```
ArrayList<String> test =new ArrayList<String>();
HashTable <ArrayList<String>, Integer> h1 = new Hashtable<Arraylist<String>, Integer>();
HashTable <ArrayList<String>, Integer> h2 = new Hashtable<Arraylist<String>, Integer>();
```

Can I possibly check if h1 contains a key (Basically an Arraylist) that is present in h2 and then replace the int value in it as in:

```
for (Hashtable <ArrayList<String>, Integer> entry : h2.entrySet()) {
    if(h1.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
    entry.replace(entry.getKey(), 1);
}
```

Or do:

```
for (Hashtable <ArrayList<String>, int> entry : h2.entrySet()) {
    if(h1.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
    h2.put(entry.getKey(),1);
}
```

?? Please do help me out...

Comment: Why `Hashtable` and not, say, `HashMap`?

Comment: Might be worth taking a step back and wrapping these structures in objects with meaning.  A complex key (like an array list of strings) might well be better represented as an object.  Similarly if `h1` and `h2` are closely related then they should be held in the same object.

Comment: Oh, and your code does not compile: `int` is not legal in generics declaration

Comment: Yeah... Sorry, I just changed that. They are actually Database rows that I'm getting from PreparedStatement. I've simply converted them to Strings and need to compare them.

Comment: They are the rows of 2 DB tables that are almost the same. I basically need to find out the discrepant rows and insert/delete them.

Comment: You may then want to have a look at Guava and its `Maps.difference()`; but please consider restructuring first ;) Collections as map keys is possible but not really recommended.

Comment: I don't know if I will be allowed to use Google Collections frankly.

Comment: I was talking about Guava, not Google Collections; Guava has many goodies, and you should absolutely use it if you can sneak the opportunity. You'll never regret it.

Comment: Just going through the documentation... Thanks. This seems really neat.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the compilation errors your last code block should do exactly what you want.

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
Hashtable <ArrayList<String>, Integer> h1 = new Hashtable <ArrayList<String>, Integer>();
Hashtable <ArrayList<String>, Integer> h2 = new Hashtable <ArrayList<String>, Integer>();
for (ArrayList<String> key : h2.keySet()) {
    if(h1.containsKey(key))
        h2.put(key, 1);
}
```

Comment: So, say my ArrayList contains ["1","Name","F-Fg-gew"] and the other contains the same thing, they will be equal? And I don't have to actually iterate through the ArrayList? Sweet!

Comment: Yes, according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):  Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.

Comment: Could you please mark the answer that helped you most as accepted using the checkmark below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can do**. Because `contains()` internally does first `hashCode()` to find out the hash bucket. And then does `equals()` with each `key` in the hash bucket with the passed search object.

- `equals()` is overriden in `ArrayList` (through `AbstractList`)

and the Javadoc says

> This implementation first checks if the specified object is this list.
>   If so, it returns true; if not, it checks if the specified object is a
>   list. If not, it returns false; if so, it iterates over both lists,
>   comparing corresponding pairs of elements. If any comparison returns
>   false, this method returns false. If either iterator runs out of
>   elements before the other it returns false (as the lists are of
>   unequal length); otherwise it returns true when the iterations
>   complete.

In other words, if 2 lists contains same elements in same sequence, they are eqaul.

- And If two `ArrayList` have same elements their `hashCode()` should be same

Comment: `Hashtable` does `.hashCode()` before `.equals()`. But `ArrayList` implements it, so...

Answer (score 0):

This is a realy funcy thing to do, and as people already have said you should seriously consider your use of datatypes. But this should do the trick.

```
Hashtable<ArrayList<String>, Integer> h3 = (Hashtable<ArrayList<String>, Integer>) h2.clone();

for(ArrayList<String> a: h2.keySet()){
    if(h1.containsKey(a)){
        h3.put(a, 1);
    }
}
h2 = h3;
```

Comment: Won't this basically return the common keys in h1 and h2 and then replace h2 with that? I basically need the uncommon keys since they represent DB Table rows that are different and then insert / delete them.